# iOS Media Framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am implementing some video into my iPad app and its works fine. But the issue I am running into is that when I leave the view to navigate somewhere else the video audio keeps playing in the background. Is there a way to completely stop the video and remove it from the view before closing the view?

I tried:

[moviePlayerController stop];  - But that does not seem to stop the movie it just crashes the app.

[moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview]; - That removes the video from the view but does not stop the audio.

This is what I have for the code:

```
- (IBAction)PlayMediaButton:(id)sender
{   

[moviePlayerController stop];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

NSString *movpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"albert" ofType:@"mp4"];
MPMoviePlayerViewController* mpviewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] 
                                                 initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movpath]];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:movpath])      //Does file exist?
{
    moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movpath]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayerController];  

    moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(38, 37, 986, 618);
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    [moviePlayerController play];

    if ([moviePlayerController respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsAirPlay:)])    //Allow airplay if availabe
        [moviePlayerController setAllowsAirPlay:YES];

    [moviePlayerController play];

}            
}



- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayerController];

    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [moviePlayerController release];
}
```

Comment: What error are you receiving when you send `-stop` to `moviePlayerController`? Where are you sending this message?

Comment: Paste your code that shows how you create the instance of `moviePlayerController` and where you are trying to call **`stop`** and **`removeFromSuperview`**.

Comment: I added what I have to call the video and when the playback is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm following you correctly, you should stop the movie player controller in `-viewWillDisappear:`.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [moviePlayerController stop];
}
```

**Edit** Just noticed that you're creating a `MPMoviePlayerViewController` instead of an `MPMoviePlayerController`. The former is meant to be displayed modally since it as a subclass of `UIViewController`. This explains the crash because `MPMoviePlayerViewController` doesn't respond to a `-stop` message. So either, display `moviePlayerController` with `-presentModalViewController:animated:` or change it's type to `MPMoviePlayerController` and add it to your view as you are doing now.

Comment: After trying that is keeps crashing the app when I try to leave the view.

Comment: Yes we understand that the app is crashing. Mind sharing with us the error that you're receiving?